# How to create new angular component in jhipster

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I have created a new project using jhipster and imported it into Intellij.
When i try to create a new angular component i get an error.Here is what i did:

File >> New >> Angular cli >> component > ok.

I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:/TestareJhipster/Testare1/node_modules/@angular/cli\bin\ng generate component cacat
Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
Done
```

Is there another way to create a component?

Comment: looks similar to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6566; related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7960. see the comments there for possible workarounds

Comment: Why not use angular-cli from your command line as described in official docs: http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular ?

Comment: Please try this approach [stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696599/2668045) Should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with JHipster is to run:

```
jhipster entity yourEntityName --skip-server
```

From JHipster official documentation ( http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/ )

> This will skip the server-side code and will generate only the
>   client-side code.

Alternatively this answer might help you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269000/2815598