# How to generate component in asp.net core 2 in spa application? like angular CLI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

1. First installed angular CLI globally:

   ```
   npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
   ```
2. Then I create an angular project outside using by CLI:

   ```
   ng new hello-world
   ```
3. Copy .angular-cli.json file into the root my project:
4. Modify .angular-cli.json file:
   "root" : "src" change to  "root" : "ClientApp"
5. I Installed angularCli dev in my root project:
   cd MyProject
6. Then

   ```
   npm install @angular/cli@latest --save-dev
   ```
7. I Went to that directory :

   ```
   cd ClientApp/app/components
   ```
8. Then I wrote: ng g c MyComponentName

It has shown me this screen:

[image]

Comment: the message say you that you have two or more module.ts in your directory. ng g c MyComponent, furthermore to create the module.ts, module.css, etc, add in the closer module.ts the import and declare

Comment: yes but how can solved that issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268181/i-cant-add-new-component-with-angular-cli-in-asp-net-core-spas/46269000#46269000

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the file `app.module.shared.ts` To `app.module.ts` under *ClientApp/app* and correct the file paths in `app.module.browser.ts` and `app.module.server.ts` accordingly.

Tested under:
*Environment : Development

Target Framework : netcoreapp2.0

SPA template : angular*