# Why does Angular 6 generate my service in the folder "e2e/app"?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When generating a new service in Angular 6 using:

```
ng generate service <service-name>
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test-ang": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test-ang:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "test-ang:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test-ang:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "test-ang-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "test-ang:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "test-ang",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

It generates the new service in the folder "e2e", how do I make it generate in "src/app" like it did before I upgraded to Angular 6 from Angular 5?

Comment: post `angular-cli.json`

Comment: Maybe you are in wrong folder, when run ng-cli commands

Comment: were you in the e2e directory while executing `ng g s` ? I tested your `angular.json` and it works fine on my machine

Answer (score 4):

Some hack may bring a temporary solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838851/9961243

In the `your-app-e2e` section of the found angular.json (in app root folder) change the entry `root` from `""` to `"e2e"`.

This changes the watched behaviour back to the deposition of template files in the src/app folder. But this may break e2e testing.

Edit:

And module-registration with `"--module=app"` may not work as expected

Comment: module-registration with "--module=app" may not work as expected

Comment: Please use the [edit] button when you want to add information to your post.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked! I changed `root` from `""` to `"ece"` in *angular.json* for the `my-app-e2e` section

Comment: -m=app worked for me. It imported the component reference to app.module.ts